# Acumatica- Production Order Alloction

Tags: acumatica

We have a wrapper screen of Production Order, and using same allocation button as on production Order,
It is working as expected when there is single line added in the allocation popup, as soon as second line is added, we are getting object reference error.

I think there is some events bind in LSProdMatlLine but these events are not fired when used by other screen.

can you please help me to provide details for using the allocation feature and overriding it.

Comment: Not enough information to give any help.  Please include any error message, stack trace, custom code, etc.  If you mean you are getting the null object message, then that tends to mean you have tried to find a record that returned null and then use it.  My common issue in this case is that I need to do something like if(MyObject != null) {...}. If this is the issue, the stack trace should tell which event or line in the code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was due to the cache inheritance problem within the same PXGraph where the Base class (INLotSerialStatus) and Derived class (LotSerialStatus) share the same cache and so, while trying to access/get the cache of the derived object, it returns the cache of the base type instead of the derived type, thus throwing the “Unable to Cast” error.

So, in order to avoid the error,  a dummy view cache for the base type before creating any other views as follows:

```
public PXSelect<INLotSerialStatus> dummyINLotSerial;
```